# PostgreSQL isn't listen on 5432 in Windows 7

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-9.2, remote, connectivity

I have a PostgreSQL 9.3.1 DB Server running in Windows 7 Ultimate. I have checked the file `postgresql.conf` and this lines are uncommented:

```
listen_addresses="*"
port=5432
```

And this is the configuration at `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             127.168.1.0/24          md5

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32           md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                md5
```

Apparently all is fine but if I run the command `netstat -an` I don't see the port 5432 open to any host unless this line:

```
0.0.0.0:5432
```

means that. The problem is I can't connect from any PC in subnet `192.168.1.x` and the message says PostgreSQL isn't installed on the PC or it doesn't listen. I have disable any firewall in all PC looking for a solution but can't. Can any help me to find the problem here?

**UPDATE**

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Please post the exact error message!

Comment: @MilenA.Radev basically the error looks like the one showed in the picture (see edition) but pointing to my local address `192.168.1.101` and port `5432`

Comment: 0.0.0.0:5432 does indeed mean that it's listening on all addresses at port 5432.

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -p TCP -a -n | find "LISTENING" | find "5432"` ?

Comment: @Colin'tHart see output `netstat -p TCP -a -n | find "LISTENING" | find "5432"` and this is `TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`

Comment: That means it really is listening on port 5432, for all IP addresses that that host is configured for. It really does sound like a firewall issue.

Comment: @Colin'tHart firewall are disabled in ESET Smart Security and also Windows default firewall, any way to reach connectivity on that port? Don't know if `telnet` to see if this is the problem really

Comment: I find Zenmap from http://www.nmap.org to be the best tool for diagnosing firewall issues. Simply enter "x.x.x.x/32" (where x.x.x.x is the IP address of your server) and "Intense scan".

Comment: BTW, it's not something as simple as specifying the wrong port in the client? The error message says port *5433*!

Comment: @Colin'tHart no, this is a example image, see my comments that the real message says port `5432`

Comment: @Colin'tHart okey, `nmap -T4 -A -v 192.168.1.100` says `Discovered open port 5432/tcp on 192.168.1.100` so problem isn't firewall, any ideas?

Comment: And this is from the same client PC that you've tried to connect using your PG client (looks like PGAdmin)?

Comment: There is a typo in the pg_hba.conf: 127 should be 192 on the second uncommented line -- assuming this line is meant to allow password connections from the LAN. But this should give a different error than the one you report.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem. I disabled all my third party antiviruses and firewalls and reinstall PostgreSQL again and its now working fine... :)